# Format HTML table elements

Tags: html, css, alignment, html-table, element

This really seems trivial but I'm unable to attain the intended. I'm trying to add a new element to the toolbox(a table within a division). But the newly added element is out of alignment.

The `Pass-through` and the `Window query` keep overlapping as shown below.
[image: Toolbox]

**HTML Table**

```
<div style="float: left;" class="toolbox" id="toolbox">
    <table>
    ...
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Simple Query</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="squery" id="rId"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Pass-through</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="nElem" id="lId"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Window Query</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="wquery" id="wId"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    ...
```

**CSS Class `nElem` for the Pass-through**

The classes for the other elements, simple query, window query, are all the same as the Pass-through's class. The only difference is the color.

```
.nElem {
    border: 1px solid #346789;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 19px #aaa;
    -o-box-shadow: 2px 2px 19px #aaa;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 19px #aaa;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 19px #aaa;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.5em;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    opacity: 0.8;
    width: 120px;
    height: 72px;
    line-height: 80px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 20;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: darkslateblue;
    color: black;
    font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 0.5em;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow 0.15s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: -moz-box-shadow 0.15s ease-in;
    -o-transition: -o-box-shadow 0.15s ease-in;
    transition: box-shadow 0.15s ease-in;   
}
```

**Toolbox(Division within which the table is created) class**

```
.toolbox {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 230px;
    height:850px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: "Helvetica";
    font-size: small;
    background: #f4f4f4;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not enough to understand what's exactly wrong. But I'm sure that the main problem is caused by `position: absolute;` for `.nElem`, `.squery`, `.wquery` and so on. So remove this property and look again.
I tried to solve your problem here: http://codepen.io/g1un/pen/ozZNkL

```
.nElem {
    /*position: absolute;*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. But, what I'd like to know is why didn't the `position: absolute;` affect the other elements(simple query, window query,etc) but affected only the pass through?

Comment: @TaraWilfred maybe you have set different `height` for some `labels`. The whole code can help to answer this question.

Comment: All the attributes are are the exact same except for the color.

Comment: @TaraWilfred Yes, it looks like absolute property was set only to 'pass-through' element (http://codepen.io/g1un/pen/bwANWP). It's better to see in dev tools of your browser what has influenced other elements not to be absolute.

Comment: Thanks again. I will